# Tell preview to get the window whose document is named "book.pdf"

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to get the window whose document has the name "book.pdf". Here's my approach

```
tell application "Preview"
    set w to every window whose document is named "book.pdf"
end
```

This doesn't work. I've tried about 100 permutations but I'm not getting anywhere. Any tips?

Comment: To me, your question is too vague. What are you trying to "get"? What is it that you want Preview app to do with the file "book.pdf"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AXTitle` combined with `contains`, and tell `System Events` not `Preview`

Note I have it wrapped in a `try` block because myWindow will be undefined if no string match is found.

```
set n to "book.pdf" -- whatever substring you want to find

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Preview"
    try
        set myWindow to (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true and value of attribute "AXTitle" contains n)
        log myWindow
    on error
        log "not found"
    end try
end tell
```